# How can I use the environment variable in database.php file in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: php, environment-variables, cakephp-2.0

I am getting the below error while trying to use the environment variable in database.php file.

**Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in app/Config/database.php**

Note: I have tried with env() as well as getenv() function, but none worked for me.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Don't tell us that you tried. Show us exactly what you have tried.

Comment: public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => getenv('DB_HOST'),
    'login' => getenv('DB_USER'),
        'password' => getenv('DB_PASS'),
        'database' => 'myDbName',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
This is what i have tried.

Comment: Yes, it's a limitation of PHP (not CakePHP) that you can't use function calls when initializing a static variable. Putting the calls in the constructor, as you've found, is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '',
        'login' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

public function __construct()
        {           
            $this->default['host'] = getenv('DB_HOST');
            $this->default['login'] = getenv('DB_USER');
            $this->default['password'] = getenv('DB_PASS');
            $this->default['database'] = getenv('DB_NAME');
        }
```

I have tried this code in the database.php file after the $default variable and now its working fine for me.